# 2 DataGridView ao clicar no primeiro jogar o registro no 2?

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou usando **WinForms**, já tenho um **Gridview** populado, agora preciso que quando o usuário *dar um duplo clique* sobre determinada linha, ele retire esse registro do primeiro grid e jogue o mesmo registro no segundo grid.

Se for possível poderia fazer isso com mais de 1 registro por vez? 
Exemplo aperto o Shift e vou clicando nos registro logo após clico no botão e ele manda para o segundo Grid.

Comment: Po, mas se você enviar assim que der o primeiro click, como vai ter referência para selecionar múltiplos? O melhor seria usar uma tecla do teclado para enviar como atalho, e um botão... enviar automaticamente no primeiro click fica estranho não?

Comment: Para enviar múltiplos seguraria o Shift, acho que vou deixar com 2 cliques, assim não tem erro. Obrigado pela observação Miguel

Comment: @William como você está fazendo o Bind do grid?

Comment: @jbueno, estou usando dgvGrupos.DataSource = bs_grupos; 
Usando o foreach da lista que Miguel passou, eu consegui migrar os registros de um grid para o outro. Só preciso ver se não vai ter problema de performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para o botão de mover os registros podes fazer assim:

```
var selectedRowCount = dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count;
if (selectedRowCount > 0)
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedRowCount; i++)
    {
        var obj = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
        pessoaBindingSource2.Add(obj);
    }
```

Note que eu tive que armazenar a quantidade de registros selecionados antes de entrar no `for`, pois o DataGridView sempre seleciona o próximo elemento quando um é eliminado... se não for assim, o que acontece é que acaba se excluindo tudo dali para baixo.

Para o duplo clique é muito mais fácil:

```
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
{
    var obj = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
    pessoaBindingSource2.Add(obj);
}
```

É necessário configurar de antemão, o data-binding de cada um dos DataGridView. Eu criei um BindingSource para cada grid.

*EDIT*

Como configurar o BindingSource:

1. [image: Abra as ações do DataViewGrid no designer]
2. [image: Selecione a opção 'Object']
3. [image: Selecione o tipo do objeto desejado]

Para preencher a BindingSource basta iterar os elementos da lista e adicioná-los ao BindingSource:

```
foreach (var item in minhaLista)
    pessoaBindingSource1.Add(item);
```

Ou assim, como meu interlocutor me ensinou num dos comentários:

```
new BindingSource() { DataSource = lista };
```

Comment: Miguel, no caso tenho uma class e usado ela como list.

 public string Nome{ get; set; }
 public string Url { get; set; }
-------
lista.Add(grupos);

Comment: Teria como reutilizar ela para fazer isso?  Olha só:         
List<Grupos> lista = new List<Grupos>();

List<Grupos> lista_selecionado = new List<Grupos>();

Comment: Tem como copiar os itens da lista para o BindingSource... mas usar a lista diretamente não tem como. Vou atualizar resposta.

Comment: Precisa mesmo usar um foreach pra fazer colocar os itens da lista no BindingSource?

Comment: Também pensei isso... mas não achei um método `AddRange` nele. Então, acho que sim. Se isso for um incômodo, sempre é possível implementar um extension-method para cobrir essa possibilidade.

Comment: Setar a lista como DataSource não funciona?

Comment: Pode até funcionar para ler os itens, mas não funciona para avisar ao DataGridView que a lista mudou. A classe `List<T>` não possui eventos para avisar ao DataGridView que algo foi adicionado nela... por isso utilizei o BindingSource, pois quando algo é adicionado nele, ele avisa para o controle que a lista foi atualizada.

Comment: @Miguel deu certo aqui! Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Sobre o foreach acabei utilizando assim: bs_grupos = new BindingSource() { DataSource = lista };

Comment: Que bom heim... tô ensinando mas também tô aprendendo! Essa última ai eu não sabia.

Comment: Precisei converter o para lista usei o seguinte código também: 
lista = BindingSource.Cast<Grupos>().ToList();

Se possível altere sua resposta para esses 2 códigos pq podem ajudar outros usuários. Novamente obrigado pela solução proposta!

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.RowCount > 0)
        {
            CODIGO = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[0,   dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value);
            CLIENTE = dataGridView1[1, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();

   dataGridView2.Rows.Add(CODIGO,CLIENTE );

        }
    }
```